# EF Code First auto dbo.AspNetUsers creation without login

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In Entity Framework Code First approach where should I put

```
public DbSet<AspNetUsers> AspNetUsers{ get; set; }
```

so as the login tables would be created when database and my own tables are created for the first time use.

Now I have to login to "force" the creation of users tables.

I need this to create foreign key to `dbo.AspNetUsers.Id`

Comment: Irrespective of when you want to create any table in code first approach, all your `DbSets` will reside in your custom DB context class which you must have created. Such a class always derives from `System.Data.Entity.DbContext`.